# "Get" is undefined in my dart code. Any solution to this?

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rB6X.png)
Please 'Get' is undefined and i can't find the solution to this.

I expect no error. I tried GetMaterialApp in my main.dart. but still doesn't work

Comment: Hi and welcome! In the future, please include the relevant snippet of code as text (in code block formatting as needed) - it makes it easier for people that are answering as they can copy-paste it, run it locally, make tweaks, etc. Also, it looks like `Get.to()` might be part of a [specific Dart library](https://pub.dev/packages/get); did the documentation for that library include steps on what imports/dependencies you need to add?

Comment: i didn't import the Get package. But I've done that and it works now. Thank you

Comment: No problem. It looks like Samuel Park gave an answer that suggests the same thing - if it was the solution, you might want to hit the checkmark next to it to mark the question as closed and thank them.

Answer (score 1):

Add this package to your project:

https://pub.dev/packages/get